# How should I configure Typescript to compile code to run in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, typescript

First, let me be clear that this is **not** related to the browser. There are a hundred different questions & answers about this that all start off with "you can't use CommonJS modules in the browser...", but that's not what I'm trying to do.

I have some Typescript code which I'm trying to compile to Javascript for execution via `node file-scanner.js` on a server. It seems like the configuration should be pretty straightforward, but I always wind up with an error: `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.

I am using `import`/`export` exclusively in my code. The main entry point looks like this:

```
import { loadEnv } from './modules/environment';
import { getDatabase } from './modules/models/helpers/database';
import { indexFiles } from './modules/services/indexFiles';

loadEnv();

getDatabase()
    .then((db) => {
        return indexFiles(db);
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
        console.error('[ERROR] Unable to index files');
        console.error(`[ERROR] Message = ${err.message}`)
        console.error('[ERROR] Error object:', err);
        console.error('[ERROR] Stack Trace', err.stack || '--no trace available--');
    });
```

And my `tsconfig.json` (copied from [@tsconfig/bases node 10 configuration](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/master/bases/node10.json)) looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es2018",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/file-scanner.ts",
    "src/modules/**/*/ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I'm building it with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p tsconfig.file-scanner.json --outDir lib
```

And running it with:

```
node lib/file-scanner.js
```

From what I understand, the Typescript compiler should be converting all my `import`/`export` statements to CommonJS `module.exports` & `require` statements. And I would hope that it includes all the appropriate code. But for some reason, when it comes time to execute the code, `exports` is not defined.

There's probably something obvious here that's staring me in the face, but I can't seem to figure it out. **How do I get Typescript to compile for execution via Node.JS?**

Comment: Right, made a typo

Comment: Your settings look correct assuming `tsconfig.file-scanner.json` is what you show as `tsconfig.json`. I wonder if your `package.json file` or something else in your environment is attempting to run the code as ESM... Like do you have `"type": "module"` in `package.json`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you! You pointed me in the right direction - I did indeed have `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`.

Comment: No problem. When you specify `"type": "module"`, NodeJS will assume you're code is written using ES Modules instead of CommonJS modules and therefore, among other differences, won't provide the `require` or `exports` or `module` variables.